# Problem with building libpqxx library on Centos 7

Tags: gcc, centos, libpqxx

I get an error during the configuration phase (./configure)

`checking for sufficient C++ language/library level... no` 
`configure: error: This libpqxx version needs at least C++17`

I have installed `devtoolset-9` and created some aliases
`alias g++="g++ -std=c++17"`
`alias cpp="cpp -std=c++17"` and so on.
`g++ version`
`g++ (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)`

How can I solve the problem?

Attempts to solve the problem I described in the question